# How do I select the name field in both this and an associated record in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have two models, "Thing" and "Category", defined like this:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category

  scope :category_name, lambda { |name| joins(:category).where("name in (?)", name) }

  # need to order by category and thing name eventually
  scope :order_alphabetically, ->{ order("name")}

end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :thing
end
```

and the schema for these look like:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150120222942) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "things", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.text     "name"
    t.text     "state",        default: "active"
    t.boolean  "enabled",      default: true
    t.integer  "category_id"
  end

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.text     "name"
    t.text     "description"
  end
```

I want to be able to do two things:
a) Sort things by thing name then category name.
b) Select just the pair (thing.name, category.name) (and maybe with the same sort order).

Oh, and I'm using postgresql as the datastore, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could join and sort:

```
Thing.joins(:comment).order('things.name, categories.name')
```

And then pluck these names:

```
Thing.joins(:comment).order('things.name, categories.name').pluck('things.name', 'categories.name')
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to give that a try right now. 

Can I then make that a scope (at least the sorting part), like:



`scope scope :order_alphabetically, ->{ joins(:comment).order("things.name, categories.name")}`

Comment: That got it perfectly. I'm trying it as a scope now.

Thanks a bunch

Comment: Yes, you can make a scope.